# Show tooltip for each line together - spline highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have prepared this **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ajL842rz/1/)**.
Where there are two lines.

Now when I move mouse to `0 deg`, as you can see for both lines, value is plotted but the problem is on hover, it will display only one line's tooltip.

*I need a vertical line where tooltips are attached for all lines **[as shown in this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qcsum9?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js,constants%2Fzoom-level.js,stockchart%2FchartOptions.js)*** - **Choose 7 days from dropdown**

I tried with

```
tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        distance: 0,
        pointFormat: `<div style="color:{series.color}"><b>{series.name} {series.unit}</b> : <b>{point.y} {series.userOptions.unit}</b></div>`,
        valueDecimals: 2,
        padding: 5,
        shared: true,
        split: false,
        enabled: true
    },
```

But unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the `split` tooltip is not available for the inverted chart, I would suggest reverting the data and adjusting the tooltip and axis settings for your requirements.

*Example data reversion:*

```
let data1 = [
  [0, 1],
  [10, 2],
  [20, 3],
];

let temperature1 = [];

data1.forEach(data => {
  temperature1.push(data.reverse())
})
```

*Example tooltip and axis's config based on your demo:*

```
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: 'Altitude'
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} km'
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    crosshair: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature'
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value}°'
    },
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    split: true,
    pointFormat: `<div style="color:{series.color}"><b>{series.name}</b> : <b>{point.y} km</b></div>`,
  },
```

**Demo**:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/41hvogue/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.crosshair
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as it creates only 1 tooltip in which all lines inform is captured. As shown in other demo example, I want different tooptip for each line being shown at a time.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Unfortunately, the `split` tooltip is not possible in the case of the inverted chart.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other high chart graph that can be used for same data ?

Comment: What about reversing the data? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cb05gqmt/

Comment: Looks good. Let me check and update you.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. You can update your answer. I will accept it.